# Slider doesn't work for div but works for images

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a simple jquery slider which works fine with the images but not with the divs that am using instead of images for sliding. It somehow breaks when I click on back button to view previous div once I view all the available divs.. 
What could be wrong with it? Am I missing something?

Also, could you please suggest me how to get the animated view (like slide effect - transition) for this slider?

Here is the demo.html:
    http://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/qybpaa6x/1/

Below is the jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Hide all DIVs wrapped within .carousel
        $('.carousel div').hide();
        /**
         * Show first slide
         * If you want to display another child, just replace
         * :first-child by :nth-child(n) where n is an integer
         */
        $('.carousel div:first-child').show();
        // Hide previous button if we're on the first slide
        if ($('.carousel div:visible').is(':first-child')) {
            $('.btn-prev').hide();
        }
        // Listen button clicks
        $('.btn-dir').click(function () {
            // Hide next button on the last slide
            if ($('.carousel div:visible').next().is(':last-child')) {
                $('.btn-next').hide();
            }
            // If button next is clicked display next slide
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'btn-dir btn-next') {
                if ($('.carousel div:visible').next().length > 0) {
                    $('.btn-prev').show();
                    $('.carousel div:visible').toggle().next().toggle();
                }
            }
            // If button prev is clicked display previous slide
            if ($(this).attr('class') == 'btn-dir btn-prev') {
                if ($('.carousel div:visible').prev().length > 0) {
                    $('.btn-next').show();
                    $('.carousel div:visible').toggle().prev().toggle();
                }
                // If we reached the first slide, hide prev button
                if ($('.carousel div:visible').is(':first-child')) {
                    $('.btn-prev').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML :

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="carousel">
        <div class="slide slide-left">
            <div class="div_sec">
                <h1>TEST1</h1>
                <input type="text" value="TEST" />
                <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-middle">
            <div class="div_sec">
                <h1>TEST2</h1>
                <input type="text" value="TEST" />
                <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <div class="div_sec">
                <h1>TEST3</h1>
                <input type="text" value="TEST" />
                <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide slide-right">
            <div class="div_sec">
                <h1>TEST4</h1>
                <input type="text" value="TEST" />
                <button>SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="direction">
    <button class="btn-dir btn-next">></button>
    <button class="btn-dir btn-prev"><</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qybpaa6x/3/)**

Made some changes to your existing carousel functionality:

> - Added an `active class` to visible `element`, which will be easy to identify while `sliding`
> - Added `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` animations.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel div').hide();
    $('.carousel div:first-child').show().addClass('active');
    //add active class to first element
    // Hide previous button if we're on the first slide
    if( $('.carousel .slide.active').is(':first-child') ) {
        //check with active class existence
        $('.btn-prev').hide();
    }
    $('.btn-dir').click(function(){
        if(!$('.carousel .slide.active').next('.slide').length) {
            $('.btn-next').hide();
        }

        //Use hasclass instead of attr('class')
        if( $(this).hasClass('btn-next') ) {
            if($('.carousel .slide.active').next('.slide').length) {
                $('.btn-prev').show();
                $('.carousel .slide.active').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                //Perform other operations like removing active class and fading in other element
                //once fadeOut is done
                    $('.slide.active').removeClass('active').next('.slide').addClass('active').fadeIn('fast')
                    if(!$('.carousel .slide.active').next('.slide').length) {
                        $('.btn-next').hide();
                    }
                })
            }

        }
        // If button prev is clicked display previous slide
        if($(this).hasClass('btn-prev')) {
            if($('.carousel .slide.active').prev('.slide').length) {
                $('.btn-next').show();
                $('.carousel .slide.active').fadeOut('slow',function(){
                    $('.slide.active').removeClass('active').prev('.slide').fadeIn('fast').addClass('active')
                    if(!$('.carousel .slide.active').prev('.slide').length) {
                        $('.btn-prev').hide();
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Guruprasad!.. How can we  set slide effect (showing div from right to left) when next button clicked.. and reverse on prev button instead of fadeIn and fadeOut?

Comment: You can use `jquery-animate` for that and you might need to modify your `CSS` too, setting the `position:absolute` and `overflow:hidden` on necessary elements and inside `animate`, you can make use of `margin-left` property to animate properly..

Comment: I tried animate function.. it was super cool.. but I dont know how to acheive that in the existing code that I have.. could you please help to achieve this with the existing code if it doesn't take much of your time?

Comment: Nice work Guruprasad, but why reinvent the wheel Sathish? (or carousel :P) Can I suggest slick slider, http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/. It's a personal favourite.

Comment: @SathishPanduga.. Also did you try to achieve the same with `twitter-bootstrap carousel`? I mean no overhead of coding for it separately.. the design looks like you are already using one?

Comment: No Guruprasad. I haven't tried it. am new to jquery.. learning from you :)

Comment: If I use twitter-bootstrap, I would have to include its extra css/js files in the web site.. for that reason, I looked for simple jquery slider.. This seems to be simple and easily understandable to customize.. but not sure how to use slide transition effect (animate) in the available one

Comment: Sure, Thanks a lot Guruprasad.

Comment: @SathishPanduga.. **[Here is the implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qybpaa6x/7/)** with **[Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**. You can explore more options from the site and believe me you'll never regret for including this tiny `css` and `js` files when you understand how much coding time it saves for you.. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! Wonderful interacting with you :) I will try to use it in my portal..

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)